# How to consume a WCF service that does not disclose its metadata, from a Windows application

Tags: wpf, windows, wcf

I am working on a WCF service using the `basicHttpBinding`.

I also set `httpsGetEnabled=false` under the `<Service>` meta data tag, to avoid disclosing metadata information.

Later I tried to consume the above WCF service from a windows application, but I am getting the following error when I tried to add the service reference from windows application.

> There was an error downloading `'https://Service/Service.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'`.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: `'https://Service/Service.svc'`.
>   There was no endpoint listening at `https://Service/Service.svc` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

How can I solve this?

In other words how can I consume a service which does not disclose its metadata information?

Please help me to solve this issue.

Best Regards,

Ranish

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not use the WSDL? The service reference wizard needs a WSDL to work. If you really don't want to transmit a WSDL in production, host it locally somewhere where you can turn WSDL **on** and point your service reference wizard to that WSDL. This way you only have to change the address to the production version once you are done developing.

That seems to be a good pattern anyway, you don't want to use your production service while still developing and debugging your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use svcutil.exe on the command line to generate the service contract classes from the assemblies for the service.

```
svcutil.exe myAssembly.dll
```

If you can include the assembly containing the service contracts in your Windows application, you can avoid service references completely and just use a `ChannelFactory<IServiceContract>` in the client.